# Reading log file and if error occurs restart service

Tags: bash, logging, grep, monitor, tail

I'm trying to create a script where it monitors a log file and if an error appears, it sends an e-mail with python. The script works, but once it detects an error, it starts spamming emails. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
# cat /usr/local/bin/monitor.bash
#!/bin/bash

tail -fn0 /var/log/syslog | while read line ; do
echo "${line}" | grep -i "error" > /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
  python emailsend.py
fi
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm planning to have this running as a service for constant monitoring of logs. Once it detects an error, I want it to sent an e-mail once, then it will restart some services(haven't added it to the script yet) and keep monitoring the file until it rotates. I hope this narrows it down a bit.

Comment: Using a proper monitoring system would overcome issues such as this.

Comment: Your problem is under-specified. Once you detected an error and sent an email what do you want to do next? Continue the monitoring on the same log file? If yes what you got is what you asked for because the error is still there. Something else (e.g. stop the monitoring, logrotate and continue the monitoring...)? Please explain.

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Dybbuk updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get logic of the code correctly, you can throw in some lines into the log to prevent getting into `if` clause and restart service.

```sh
# cat /usr/local/bin/monitor.bash
#!/bin/bash

tail -fn0 /var/log/syslog | while read line ; do
echo "${line}" | grep -i "error" > /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
  python emailsend.py
  # append line to the log to prevent grepping of 'error'
  echo 'dummy line' >> /var/log/syslog
  # restart your services here
fi
done
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes thank you the dummy line seemed to do the trick